# AWS SQS: How to send a message to SQS queue with an attachments/ list of MultipartFile and listen to SQS queue and read back the same message

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to build an email microservice using spring boot and AWS.  When an API for emailSend is called, it  will receive a data like below

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendSimpleEmail(String recipient, String msgBody, String subject, List<MultipartFile> attachments)

@ApiOperation(value = "send simple email without attachments", nickname = "sendSimpleEmail", notes = "send simple email", authorizations = {
    
    @Authorization(value = "BasicAuth")
     }, tags={ "SendSimpleEmail", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "success") })
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/api/sendemail/",
    consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }
)
ResponseEntity<Void> sendSimpleEmail(@ApiParam(value = "to address", required = true) @Valid @RequestPart(value = "recipient", required = true) String recipient,@ApiParam(value = "message", required = true) @Valid @RequestPart(value = "msgBody", required = true) String msgBody,@ApiParam(value = "subject", required = true) @Valid @RequestPart(value = "subject", required = true) String subject,@ApiParam(value = "email attachments") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments);
```

Now I have to send these above details to AWS SQS and I should be able to read the same from SQS queue.

Do we have to use S3 bucket to store attachments?

Comment: Yes, you need to use S3, either manually or by using an sqs client on both ends that automatically uploads to and reads from S3. Aka the SQSExtendedClient in java.

Comment: @luk2302': Thank you for your response, there might be 1000's of recipients and 1000's of attachments, how to store and retrieve them from S3? how to find a specific attachment for specific client?